# Ethernet cable connected to WIFI router. Speed not matching the provided ISP

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet, internet-connection

I have a internet connection broadband of 75 Mbps connection speed. When I am connecting the ethernet cable directly to my PC desktop I am getting speeds of 60-70 Mbps in speed tests. The same ethernet cable when i am connecting to my LAN port available in the WIFI router for getting wireless I am getting speeds of 8-10 Mbps. Why the loss?
Is there any mistake? Or any technical aspect I am missing.

Comment: What's the model of your Wi-Fi router, and of your devices that are trying to connect? (If they're laptops – then of their WiFi cards specifically.) Even Ethernet connections run at 3 different speeds, and for Wi-Fi there are at least 6 different revisions – e.g. are you trying to use an ancient 802.11b router and expecting 802.11n or .11ac speeds out of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection may be limited by the router's performance. On an older device what you see might actually be its peak performance.

The 8-10 Mbit/s might also indicate a link of just 10 Mbit/s. Make sure that all interfaces are set to Auto Negotiation.  Also, the router may just have a 10 Mbit/s WAN port, check its specifications.